# Blender 2.90 Alpha - Stereoscopy, how do i render interlaced output?

Tags: stereoscopy

When you turn on stereoscopy, then you will find the menu item Set Stereo 3D in the Windows menu. Here you can find other methods to display the stereoscopic image. Interlaced for example. The viewport displays the result then.

You can find similar settings in the Output panel in the Properties editor. But when i change the method and render the image, then the result is still rendered as anaglyph. And not as interlaced.

How do i render an interlaced result instead of an anaglyph one? And what is this settings in the output panel good for then? They seem to do nothing.

Kind regards - Tiles

[image]

Comment: It seems that these settings affects the image when you save it out. When i save the image from the image editor, then i get my interlaced result. It just doesn't display in the image editor.

Comment: It is indeed a bug. https://developer.blender.org/T77861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do I render interlaced output"?
"Interlaced" is a **viewing** method.
When your window renders the image, it displays a **composite**.
If you need to further grade and edit your stereo footage (sequence):
You export a L+R sequence. Use an external compositor like Nuke, Katana or AE. Export side by side (up down or L+R) in the same aspect ratio you intend to view your stereoscopy (long technical explanation about 3D compression, format and playback inserted here).

Comment: Technically yes The question should have been how do i display a rendered interlaced result in the image editor like in the 3d view. It remains an unfixed bug though. The viewport displays the composited rendered result with overlaying both images. The image editor not.

Comment: Correct. I made a quick test. The image editor supports anaglyph and side by side compositing stereo